# Перехват пакетов в топологии "Звезда" для локальной сети

Tags: сеть, трафик, wireshark, пакет

При использовании этой топологии все данные, которые поступают на устройство, связывающие сетевые устройства в Звезду рассылаются между всеми сетевыми устройствами в звезде и если сетевое устройство видит (сравнение по MAC-адресу или IP-адресу) что фрейм/пакет не для него, то оно этот пакет отбрасывает.

Так вот, это отбрасывание происходит на уровне микроконтроллера/процессора сетевого адаптера, или выше, на уровне ОС?

Я решил поэкспериментировать с этим.

В Wireshark'e есть опция "Capture all packets in promiscuous mode", она позволяет получать все пакеты, которые адресованы не только моему сетевому адаптеру.

Получается, что отбрасывание идет на уровне ОС?

Но, я пингую сервер на втором компе из Звезды, а Wireshark на моем не видит ответов от пинга с того компа, при включенном "Capture all packets in promiscuous mode".

Может защита на роутере идет?

Comment: Скорее всего отбрасывает этот пакет сетевое оборудование (например Ethernet switch) так как именно в него включены все устройства

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас ошибка в методологии. Топология "звезда" и сетевой концентратор (он же "хаб", устройство ныне почти музейное) - это не синонимы. На все порты трафик рассылает хаб. У вас сто пудов стоит свич. Он сперва смотрит, на каком порту у него такой мак, а потом только на этот порт и шлет пакет.
Свич можно заставить работать как хаб, это называется [переполнение таблицы mac-адресов](https://yandex.ru/search/?msid=1493209574.00963.22912.30024&text=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%20mac%20%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2&lr=213). Если свич ваш - можете попробовать. Если не ваш - не надо, админы найдут и стукнут.
У свича еще может быть режим [зеркалирования трафика](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=1403.hzLa-of6_bnh9XhxNN_HnXp1voQ-gGaeu0weECa4DJTtYkqYij_kEbnlAWkKmdWF.61aa850068732f3631ea78f049cad93410d0d50c&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9XPOnieP7YQBovzVqj9ang0YEepmskggOQ&data=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&b64e=2&sign=79a871f5f0fe20e60e2148ef0296efbb&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszkyqYoOuf-joc5B9qncbeuotLg3fEWHg4F_ni-nHf40oi7gsEmJyLS7HV7ufUFvZqfLN8cvzCW6WFBvGGtjOWEIizODmuGdAe5B4EOuWBjDaIKA_U7d7ipT-MNdQKUZD2tHKMZ1Nf8DrQx7662Sql5JJeqhIb2g4lIWfO-ui_nGSY_V_P2oNueRz42iEEN95y1ABSpiGAOWjdxjkFCXEEGMBGl8eCmctk5ds0PL-qFtQO&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kphK_smoXvvfj0kJ10MBPj2IXob-lzcfqaXKf3gJ3-yfP-hYPNgBKi_8doDGi8tefCANVcPmgduh6qQS8l_ozfvb2vpNzy3eRLWi38JoZNRYQlYiv3gjw1gMq5totzB1f2EoVTlsWUjjY-5qQhQEEr8rtVERGcCzXyTwKp4RZT0FDV1d_QT7LoLZpjqOXTRtp3x4F2bLYj9Ss&l10n=ru&cts=1493209813098&mc=4.580023372597455). Опять же если свич ваш и так умеет - можете попробовать.
Можно сделать так, чтобы ваш ПК с  Wireshark был default gateway для остальных станций. Тогда весь свой нелокальный трафик они пошлют вам сами, добровольно и с песней. И вы его увидите.

Comment: Раз уж вы начали говорить о уязвимостях, то кроме переполнения таблицы mac-адресов стоит упомянуть ARP-spoofing (он же ARP-poisoning), DHCP-spoofing, MAC-spoofing и редкий уже ICMP-spoofing.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. Хаб рассылает входящие пакеты всем устройствами подключенным к нему, а у свича к каждому его разъему привязывается mac-адрес сетевого устройства.

  
Получается, что устройство, в которое подключаются компы локальной сети это несколько устройств в одном.
И это устройство может быть разным.

У меня стоит роутер. Он включает в себя свич?

Comment: Роутер - это как минимум NAT-маршрутизатор плюс свич. Если оба компа (и тестер, и подопытный) подключены к LAN-портам, то для них роутер работает как свич.

Comment: Интересно, а в более древних локальных сетях, компы  сети объединялись сразу хабом, т.е. входящий пакет всегда шел на все компы? Хотя это наверно от топологии локалки зависит.

Comment: В более древних - это в каких? Тонкий и толстый ethernet - это общая шина, там хаба нет, там все (сегмент) на одном проводе. Arcnet - там были хабы и только хабы. TokenRing был сразу маршрутизируемый. Если же вы про давние сети на utp-ethernet - то таки да, там были хабы (концентраторы), годах в 1995-2000 ничего иного и не было.

Comment: То есть каждая топология локалки по-своему выходит в интернет — через определенное сетевое устройство, которое определяется топлогией.
А может быть так, что одна и таже топология выходит в интернет через разные сетевые устройства.

Comment: Интернет - это тоже сеть. Фактически, вы спрашиваете, может ли быть между сетями более одного маршрута. Ответ - да, может.

Answer (score 4):

Сетевые пакеты передаются активным оборудованием только на тот порт, на котором зарегистрирован МАС-адрес либо IP-адрес приёмника, если этот адрес ему известен (имеется в таблице коммутации). Если адрес неизвестен (режим самообучения), а также при отключенном режиме самообучения и при переполнении таблицы коммутации - пакет дублируется во все порты. И это мы ещё не рассматриваем ограничения, связанные с VLAN и прочими наворотами...

Для того, чтобы такие пакеты не отбрасывались активным сетевым оборудованием и транслировались на порт, на котором адрес назначения не зарегистрирован, необходимо либо отключить функцию самообучения (фактически превратив коммутатор в хаб), либо включить зеркалирование порта (копирование пакетов, проходящих через один порт, в другой порт, вне зависимости от информации в таблице коммутации).

Кроме того, пакеты, не предназначенные данной рабочей станции (транзитные) отбрасываются уже на рабочей станции (эта функция может выполняться как самой сетевой картой, так и обслуживающим её драйвером). Чтобы этого не происходило, необходимо переключить интерфейс в режим приёма транзитных пакетов (promiscuous mode).